# [Prisma][Mongo] Can't delete model with relations - The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I am using Mongodb with Prisma, and I have a very weird case where I can't delete

```
model EmployeeTask {
  id                         String   @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  employeeId                 String   @unique
  employee                   Employee @relation(fields: [employeeId], references: [id])
  taskId                     String   @unique
  task                       Task     @relation(fields: [taskId], references: [id])
}

model Task {
  id                         String         @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  employeeTasks              EmployeeTask[]
}
```

I am attempting to delete a Task and its corresponding EmployeeTasks however no matter what I do I keep getting this error:

```
The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'EmployeeTaskToTask' between the `EmployeeTask` and `Task` models.
```

I have tried to first update the ids to disconnect and then delete, but no matter what I do it doesnt work.

I am using MongoDB

```
  async delete() {
    const deletedTask = await this.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
      const updatedEmployeeTasks = await tx.employeeTask.updateMany({
        where: { taskId: this.taskId },
        data: {
          taskId: "",
          employeeId: "",
        },
      });

      const deletedEmployeeTasks = await tx.employeeTask.deleteMany({
        where: { taskId: "" }, // or taskid: this.taskId without updating to empty string first
      });
   
      const deletedTask = await this.prisma.task.delete({
        where: { id: this.taskId },
      });

  

      return deletedTask;
    });

    return deletedTask;
  }
```

I have also tried first deleting the `employeeTasks` outside of the transaction (which works), and then even when I dont have any connected `employeeTasks` to the `task`, I still get the same error.